# Typed HttpClient only works with CreateClient() from WebApplicationFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I made a client for the default WeatherForecast API project, that I want to use in an integration test:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace API_ClientTest
{

    public class WeatherClient : IWeatherClient
    {
        public HttpClient _client { get; }

        public WeatherClient(HttpClient client)
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:80/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept",
            "application/json");
            _client = client;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetWeatherForecast()
        {
            var response = await _client.GetAsync("weatherforecast");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

}


    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace API_ClientTest
    {
        public interface IWeatherClient
        {
            Task<string> GetWeatherForecast();
        }
    }
```

For my integration tests I use WebApplicationFactory:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace API_ClientTest
{
    public class WeatherServiceFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // Build the service provider.
                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                //Typed clients (because types are cool)
                services.AddHttpClient("WeatherClient")
                .AddTypedClient<WeatherClient>()
                .AddTypedClient<IWeatherClient, WeatherClient>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Xunit;

namespace API_ClientTest
{
    public class WeatherServiceTest : IClassFixture<WeatherServiceFactory<API_ClientTest.Startup>>
    {
        private readonly WeatherServiceFactory<API_ClientTest.Startup>
           _factory;
        public WeatherServiceTest(WeatherServiceFactory<API_ClientTest.Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Get_GenerateResponse()
        {
            // Arrange
            var weatherClient = _factory.Services.GetRequiredService<IWeatherClient>();
            var factoryClient = _factory.CreateClient();
            // Works
            var factoryResponse = await factoryClient.GetAsync("weatherforecast");
            // Does not work
            var response = await weatherClient.GetWeatherForecast();
        }
    }
}
```

So the client from the factory can communicate with the API, but the one from Dependency Injection (which I take from the services of the factory) throws a System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException.

```
Message: 
    System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : No connection could be made because the target machine refused it. (Translated by author)
    ---- System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte.
  Stack Trace: 
    ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
    WeatherClient.GetWeatherForecast() line 24
    WeatherServiceTest.Get_GenerateResponse() line 26
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
    ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Could you explain me the reason for the different behaviour? Thank you

Edit: The HttpClient from the factory directly communicates with the WebApi, while the HttpClient from WeatherService sends an http request to localhost over the network. The goal is to recreate the behaviour of the first HttpClient, in my WeatherClient.

A temporary workaround is to initialize the typed Client with the HttpClient instance from the factory:

```
var weatherClient = new WeatherClient (_factory.CreateClient());
```

Comment: Can you post the `HttpRequestException` stack trace? It would help if we knew what the error message is.

Comment: You're reassinging the lambda variable client in the callback to AddHttpClient, but that's not how that works (the assignment is thrown away) . You could instead try registering a delegate that manually constructs your service, passing this.CreateClient as its constructor parameter `services.AddScoped<IWeatherClient>(_ => new WeatherClient(this.CreateClient())`. That might work, but I'm not sure. Also why do you build the provider and then add more services to it?

Comment: Oh snap, I forgot to remove that part. As you stated, my goal was to use the same HttpClient that the factory would create, inside my service. It has not worked out so far (even with your suggestion), but I got a little closer to the root of problem: one call is redirected internaly to the WeatherApi, the other creates a real http-call to localhost (as I could see the request in my Fiddler tool).

The reason I add a service is, because it is not registered on the API side. I therefore need to register one more service.

Comment: what is `this.CreateClient()` that seems like an antipattern.

Comment: this.CreateClient() creates a client from the factory. It might be an antipattern, but as you can see, only the Client coming from this function ( _factory.CreateClient() ) has managed to make calls to the WeatherAPI. About the function itself in the context of integration testing, I took it from the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1